# How to make circle disappear over time

Tags: c++, c, raylib

[image: My Game]
I want to pop that green circle when I clicked to the window on cursors position and disappear it overtime. Like MOBA Games(League of Legends)

I tried to set circle position to mouse position every time I clicked and not change it through the loop(because I want it to stay where I clicked not follow the mouse). And also to disappear the circle I tried to update radius and opacity of circle every second. But the result was instant disappear of circle. I also tried different methods and loops to update radius and opacity like playing with numbers or using while method instead of for loop. But the result was instant appear and disappear of circle or crash error. Here is my code:

```
void draw_cursor()
{
    if (IsMouseButtonPressed(MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT))
    {
      float currentPosX = GetMousePosition().x;
      float currentPosY = GetMousePosition().y;
      float cursor_radius = 10.0f;
      int cursor_opacity = 200;
      for (float cursor_radius_for = cursor_radius; cursor_radius_for > 0; cursor_radius_for -= 1)
      {
          if (deltaTime() * 60 > 0)
          {
              cursor_radius -= cursor_radius / 20 * deltaTime() * 60;
              cursor_opacity -= cursor_opacity / 20 * deltaTime() * 60;
          }
          DrawCircle(currentPosX, currentPosY, cursor_radius, (Color){0, 255, 0, cursor_opacity});
      }
    }    
}
```

Like I mentioned above this code pops up the circle just for a millisecond and then it disappears. But I want that to be slow not an instant action.

Comment: "overtime" --> "over time".

Comment: @gregspears What you suggested is not making any difference to instant appear and disappear. And also why did you expect that paranthesis will make any difference there is no  process priority in multiplication and division ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `raylib`, so take my answer as an educated guess.

Judging by the [readme](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib), this framework seems to be similar to many other drawing frameworks like [`p5.js`](https://github.com/processing/p5.js), where you have a draw loop and some privatives that helps you clear the canvas and draw shapes, text, etc. This has many implications that impact how you design your code. One of them is that the draw loop should complete for each frame.

In the code you provided, you are drawing all the circles in `draw_cursor`, without 'taking a break' and giving the opportunity to the main loop to iterate and actually draw the frame to screen. This has the effect of drawing only one single (long) frame, and then moving on. You should in fact see your app to be apparently hanging for the lifetime of your circle.

I think this should do the job:

```c
#define CIRCLE_LIFETIME 60 // in seconds
#define CIRCLE_FADE_TIME 20 // in seconds

void draw_cursor()
{
  static bool isCircleVisible = false;
  static float circleX, circleY;
  static double circleBirth; // timestamp when user clicked left mouse button 

  if (IsMouseButtonPressed(MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT))
  {
    isCircleVisible = true;
    circleX = GetMousePosition().x;
    circleY = GetMousePosition().y;
    circleBirth = GetTime();
  }

  double now = GetTime();
  if (isCircleVisible && (now - circleBirth) > CIRCLE_LIFETIME + CIRCLE_FADE_TIME)
  {
    isCircleVisible = false;
    return;
  }

  if (isCircleVisible)
  {
    float fadeTimeDone = max(0, now - circleBirth - CIRCLE_LIFETIME);
    float progress = 1 - fadeTimeDone / CIRCLE_FADE_TIME;
    float radius = 10 * progress;
    int opacity = (int)(255 * progress);

    DrawCircle(circleX, circleY, radius, (Color){0, 255, 0, opacity});
  }
}
```

This is a simplified version of what you might need: this handles only one circle at a time (if the user clicks another time the previous circle disappears), but should answer your question.

Comment: Let me know if it works. If it does and you would like more details, I can add an explanation on how my code works

Comment: First of all thank you for your nice and clear expression. I am now trying to implement it. I'll flag you if it works. Thank you very much

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. You made my day thank you very much. I'm very new to programming, c++, object oriented programming, raylib, etc... And this is a very clear expression of how to handle things separetely and properly. Thank you very much.

Comment: I just didn't get one point. Why are you defining progress variable like this and what is it actually?

Comment: [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/isei6hkbyb) should make clearer what is happening

Comment: Wow ok I got it. Very clear expression again. Thank you very much for everything.  Take care...